# Why plan a movie in space instead of using CGI technology (visual effects)?

Tags: production

Recently I heard that NASA confirmed their plan to work with Tom Cruise and Elon Musk's SpaceX on a film that would be shot in outer space.

I was amazed with Hollywood CGI effects shown in recent films, like the *Planet of the Apes* movies. It seems to me that using CGI technology for simulating space would save a lot of money compared to planning a movie in space.

So why spend these space expenses instead of using CGI?

Comment: Not sure why you think filming in space would be expensive. It's likely that SpaceX will underwrite a considerable portion of the cost (for getting into space) rather than charge the studio. Also, CGI is NOT as cheap as you might think.

Comment: @Paulie_D You might want to flesh out these considerations into an answer. Personally, when I think of "going to space" this sounds like one of the most expensive endeavours humans could do indeed (and I'd bet sure me and the OP aren't the only ones thinking so). But if you can explain why it isn't, especially compared to "normal" film-making and with relation to the business procedure SpaceX would go about, that could be helpful.

Comment: Define space and expensive. After all, the latest estimates for a ticket on Virgin Galactic have been around $250,000 per person. And, the entire movie does not have to be shot in space for it to get the title of the first to shoot in space.

Comment: @PaulieD CGI is cheap enough that they made *The Expanse* look very good on every shot which just involved space suits and ships. What didn't work was hair and clothing. Drinking was also a fail.

Comment: CGI might be needed *anyway* to "re-dress" the setting.  There's no guarantee that the ISS is a suitable background (e.g. visually distracting, doesn't fit the plot/setting, continuity issues, lighting issues, etc.).  *Apollo 13* installed accurate sets in the Vomit Comet, but it's not worth the expense to haul an entire set to orbit.  A green screen is possible, *with CGI added post-production*.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody brought up the Kubrick series from the 70s...

Comment: “recent films, like the Planet of the Apes movies” — nothing else in the three years since *War for the Planet of the Apes* came out impressed you, effects-wise?

Comment: I'm going to break the rules and answer the question in a comment: because then he can say he did it, and he was the first to do it, and he did his own stunts and damn(!) were they some f'ing fine stunts!

Comment: Interesting counterpoints to "Going to space" is more expensive than CGI. The recent indian mission to mars was cheaper than the budget of the Movie gravity, or even ironically the budget of the movie about the same mission (Chandrayaan the movie vs the mission).

Comment: [Tom Cruise in space, now where did I hear that idea before?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/201_(South_Park))

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Paulie's point is not that going to space isn't expensive on the whole, but rather that it might not be expensive _for the movie studio_, if and when SpaceX underwrites the cost (partially or in full). Which they might do because of their own marketing gains from having the movie made in the first place.

Comment: @Flater Sure, which can all go into a proper answer.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Everyone and their dog will go see the publicity stunt that is the first movie made in *real* space by a famous actor, headed by the world's foremost space agency and the world's richest egomaniac... Considering going to space now *only* costs in the low hundreds of millions and [some movies produce over 1 billion in returns,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films) you’re looking at a pretty good risk-to-profit ratio.

Much like the recent probe launched by [Dubai to Mars](https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/07/hope-probe-launches-sunday-beginning-seven-month-journey-to-mars/) that only cost 200 million, a project almost entirely only done for advertising/marketing/inspiring STEM among their own youths, this movie project could and will be a huge advertising for all the above mentioned groups, and importantly youths.

At least it’ll be spun off that way.

In the end, it’s a way for Tom Cruise and Elon Musk to gloat and show off, and potentially make a huge profit.

Comment: The cost of a seat on a Falcon 9 is less than Tom Cruise gets paid for some of his movies.

Comment: I don't think a guaranteed cost of a few hundred million dollars versus a chance your movie will gross billions is a worthwhile risk. Only a fraction of the films ever made have realised a profit that large.

Comment: @pyro it’s clearly a risk, however i feel you’re overestimating the general audience.

Comment: Objection: *second* richest egomaniac, if that.

Comment: The insurance for putting Cruise on a spaceship will be interesting though

Comment: And Cruise gets to the ISS.

Answer (score 39):

Other than the publicity stunt, which it most definitely is when compared to the cost of CGI, there is one thing we can't believably CGI away: microgravity.

When actors are in harnesses to simulate microgravity, you can generally tell. Also, their hair will still obey the laws of gravity, as will any object they interact with. That doesn't matter much when it's one small shot in a movie, but it does very much matter if the movie spends a significant time in microgravity and is aiming for some degree of realism.

The best way to inprove the realism is by building a set on a plane which goes in freefall (better known as [the Vomit Comet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ1ZozXp2tw). It creates believable microgravity for the actors and their surroundings (e.g. Apollo 13 used it to great effect), but a plane cannot freefall very long and you end up with short scenes (or frequent cuts).

[Apollo 13 behind the scenes footage for the microgravity scenes](https://youtu.be/SdgELXIeY3I?t=311).

If you compare Apollo 13 to Gravity, Apollo 13 feels a lot more believable from a physics point of view.

Shooting a movie in space would allow for significantly longer takes of a microgravity environment, since you'd actually be in an *actual* microgravity environment.

That being said, I very much doubt it's going to be cost-effective, and thus we get back to the already made "publicity stunt" argument.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111440/discussion-on-answer-by-flater-why-plan-a-movie-in-space-instead-of-using-cgi-te).

Comment: @Flater My point is that a faithful portrayal of reality is not their aim. As with all Hollywood movies, selling a lot of tickets is their aim. They did not sit in a brainstorm session saying "What did people not like about Gravity? It was the hair. If the hair had been accurate, it would have sold more tickets". They started with a gimmick: filming in space. Just because that will mean it should be more realistic than CGI efforts, does not mean that's the goal they started with

Comment: @Michael: You're responding to a point I never made. This answer does not focus on how to sell tickets to viewers.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what your main point is. OP asked why they're doing it this way, and you talk about all of the insufficiencies of CGI, but the insuffuciencies of CGI are not why they're doing it this way.

Comment: @Michael: OP's question relies on the assertion that using CGI nets an equal result to shooting scenes in microgravity. This answer points out the differences/complexities in using CGI to replace shooting in actual microgravity.

Comment: That'd be all well and good, but he didn't say the results were the same. He just said CGI results were amazing, and I agree that they are.